# Getting "Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionError: connect ENOENT" when connecting to SQL Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm setting up a NodeJS backend in Google App Engine, and when I try to connect to the SQL Cloud (using sequelize + postgres) , I'm getting this error:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionError: connect ENOENT /cloudsql/tar:us-central1:dbpointofsales/.s.PGSQL.5432
    at connection.connect.err (/home/mf/backend/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:182:24)
    at Connection.connectingErrorHandler (/home/mf/backend/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:163:14)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Socket.reportStreamError (/home/mf/backend/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:71:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Answer (score 1):

Connect ENOENT means that the system cannot connect to mysql because its path is incorrect.
Update the models / index.js files with the specified code. To find your path to the mysql socket, go to the file here /etc/mysql/my.cnf(this path may depend on your server). Example,  /etc/my.cnf. Here you will find the path of the socket.

Please veritfy, it needs administer rights (sudo on ubuntu).
Confirm the login credentials are correct, the port is open.

You have to verify the setting up a connection, and the you can try confirm the connection.

Testing the connection

sequelize

.authenticate()

.then(() => {

```
console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
```

})

.catch(err => {

```
console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
```

});

The module mysql with a key socketPath.

var sequelize = new Sequelize("database", username, password, {

```
host: "localhost",

dialect: "mysql",

logging: function () {},

pool: {

    max: 5,

    min: 0,

    idle: 10000

},

dialectOptions: {

    socketPath: "/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock"

},

define: {

    paranoid: true

}
```

});